# How to obtain a lower triangular matrix from a vector of coefficients

Tags: matrix-equations

I have a vector
$$
\mathbf{x} = (x_{21},x_{31},x_{32},x_{41}, x_{42}x_{51} , x_{52} , x_{53} , x_{54})^T
$$
and I need to find a way, using some matrix operations, to derive this matrix here
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
x_{21} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
x_{31} & x_{32} & 1 & 0 & 0\\
x_{41} & x_{42} & -(x_{31}x_{41}+x_{32}x_{42}) & 1 & 0\\
x_{51} & x_{52} & x_{53} & x_{54} & 1\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Is that possible?

If that is not possible, it may be sufficient to obtain just a vector with the non-zero elements of a selected column.

Thanks